# SPN setup for Sharepoint 2013 deployment

Tags: setspn

Is setting up SPN required for 2013 deployment? if yes, why do we need it. If not, why should I set it? Any benefits or another layer of complexity as there are endless complexity with SP 2013 deployment.

Comment: I think SPN is required if you are configuring Kerberos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPN is part of Kerberos Configuration, If you using the Kerbros Authentication Method in your SharePoint farm, then you need the SPNs.

But if you are not using / Planning to use Kerberos Auth then no need of SPN.

Creating only SPN does not give you any benifit. Please read the technet article for more understanding about it.

> The Kerberos protocol supports an authentication method that uses
>   tickets that a trusted source provides. Kerberos tickets indicate that
>   the network credentials of a user who is associated with a client
>   computer were authenticated. Th
>   e Kerberos protocol defines how users
>   interact with a network service to gain access to network resources.
>   The Kerberos Key Distribution Center (KDC) issues a
>   ticket-granting-ticket (TGT) to a client computer on behalf of a user.
>   In Windows, the client computer is a member of an Active Directory
>   Domain Services (AD DS) domain and the TGT is proof that the domain
>   controller authenticated the user credentials.

[Plan for Kerberos authentication in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806870.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Configure Kerberos authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263449(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Can the kerberos be enabled later if needed

Comment: Yes all the time, when ever u want.